# calculation the sum of total time of all the previous entries in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hai i have to calculate the time of all the previous entries on the table based on **hr_temp_id**  my table structure

```
play_id | hr_temp_id  |  min_id    |    
29      | 43          |  00:00:10  |    
30      | 43          |  00:02:00  |    
31      | 43          |  00:00:10  |    
32      | 44          |  00:00:10  |    
33      | 44          |  00:03:15  |
```

i tried something like

```
select r.min_id, (select sum(r2.min_id) from ciam_playlist_template r2 
where r2.min_id <= r.min_id) as cumesum from ciam_playlist_template r 
where r.hr_temp_id=43
```

i got result like

```
00:00:10 | 10
00:02:00 | 210
00:00:10 | 10
```

expected results

```
00:00:10
00:02:10
00:02:20
00:00:10
00:03:25
```

any suggetions?

Comment: Is desired results within your example data the expected result?

Comment: Yeah, give us the expected result!

Comment: yes thats the expected result @RaymondNijland

Comment: `SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(...))`

Comment: i've editted your question so the expected results are better visible within the question.

Comment: oh thank you for doing that

Comment: @Strawberry can you give more description

Comment: is column play_id a primary id with auto_increment?

Comment: yes it was an auto increment column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(play_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,hr_temp_id  INT NOT NULL
,min_id TIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(29,43,'00:00:10'),
(30,43,'00:02:00'),
(31,43,'00:00:10'),
(32,44,'00:00:10'),
(33,44,'00:03:15');

SELECT x.*
     , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(y.min_id))) running 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.hr_temp_id = x.hr_temp_id 
   AND y.play_id <= x.play_id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.play_id;
+---------+------------+----------+----------+
| play_id | hr_temp_id | min_id   | running  |
+---------+------------+----------+----------+
|      29 |         43 | 00:00:10 | 00:00:10 |
|      30 |         43 | 00:02:00 | 00:02:10 |
|      31 |         43 | 00:00:10 | 00:02:20 |
|      32 |         44 | 00:00:10 | 00:00:10 |
|      33 |         44 | 00:03:15 | 00:03:25 |
+---------+------------+----------+----------+
```

...or...

```
SELECT x.*
     , SEC_TO_TIME(CASE WHEN @prev = hr_temp_id THEN @i:= @i+TIME_TO_SEC(min_id) ELSE @i:=TIME_TO_SEC(min_id) END) running
     , @prev := hr_temp_id prev 
  FROM my_table x
     , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
  ORDER 
     BY hr_temp_id
      , play_id;
```

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj the first query only works if column play_id is still a primary key with auto_increment.

Comment: @RaymondNijland It needs to be unique (and sequential). That's all.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 These are standard patterns for this kind of query.

Comment: "It needs to be unique (and sequential). That's all"  yes offcource thats what iam trying to tell with primary key and auto_increment.

Comment: And, it's a requirement of both queries.